# VBA Send email with Outlook from background

Tags: vba, email, outlook, scheduled-tasks

I'm running VBA code in background using windows task scheduler.
One of my need it's to send some emails.
The code works great if I run it manually, but can't send the emails if the task is running in background. It doesn't register any errors, simply it doesn't send the email.

Here it's the related code:

```
Public Sub sendToMail()

Dim arrayMail(2, 5) As String
Dim cdfHoy As String
Dim anyMesDia As String

cdfHoy = Format(Date, "DD-MM")
anyMesDia = Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")

arrayMail(0, 0) = "example@example.com"
arrayMail(0, 1) = ""
arrayMail(0, 2) = "Test"
arrayMail(0, 3) = ""
arrayMail(0, 4) = "D:\data\file.txt;D:\data\file2.txt;"

arrayMail(1, 0) = "example2@example.com"
arrayMail(1, 1) = ""
arrayMail(1, 2) = "Test"
arrayMail(1, 3) = ""
arrayMail(1, 4) = "D:\data\file3.txt;D:\data\file4.txt;"

Call sendMail(arrayMail)
    
End Sub


Private Sub sendMail(arrayMail() As String)
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Integer
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim Email As Object
Dim iAttached As Integer
Dim attached As String
Dim start As Integer
Dim ends As Integer

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Check if Outlook is open
On Error Resume Next
Set OutApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
Err.Clear
If OutApp Is Nothing Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For k = 0 To ArrayLen(arrayMail) - 1
    Set Email = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    'Attached files
    iAttached= Len(arrayMail(k, 4)) - Len(Replace(arrayMail(k, 4), ";", ""))
    
    'Create the mail and send
    With Email
        .To = arrayMail(k, 0)
        .CC = arrayMail(k, 1)
        .Subject = arrayMail(k, 2)
        .HTMLBody = arrayMail(k, 3)
        For i = 1 To iAttached
            
            If i = 1 Then
                attached = Left(arrayMail(k, 4), InStr(arrayMail(k, 4), ";") - 1)
            Else
                start = CharPos(arrayMail(k, 4), ";", i - 1) + 1
                ends = CharPos(arrayMail(k, 4), ";", i) - start
                attached = Mid(arrayMail(k, 4), start, ends)
            End If
            
            .Attachments.Add (attached)
        Next i
        .SEND
    End With

Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` to see the error so that you can debug it?

Comment: Done, no errors.

Comment: Maybe it is a question of the user context/environment?

Comment: I think it would be worthwhile to stop trying to automate Outlook for that. You could convert this code to PowerShell ([`Send-MailMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage)) or use a batch file and a command-line mail tool like [blat](http://www.blat.net/). Both things would be faster and more reliable than your current approach.

Comment: That it's true @Tomalak